# Java stack overflow error with recursion

Tags: java

I have this code that keeps giving me stack overflow errors and I don't know how to fix it (i'm new to recursion). what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Excellent time to learn how to debug.

Comment: What is `alist` here?

Comment: Why do you call process twice?

Comment: Don't increment `row` or decrement `column`; just use `row + 1` and `column - 1` where appropriate.

Comment: As I said in my answer, try and declare `row` and `column` as `final` in your method declaration... Then see how you would code your method in this case...

Answer (score 6):

The

```
        process(a, sum, row++, column);
```

unconditionally calls the function *with exactly the same arguments* due to the use of *post*-increment (hat tip to @fge for spotting this). This immediately leads to infinite recursion.

Once you fix this, you'll run into another problem: you are checking that `row` *equals* `a.length - 1`, and your code can make it *exceed* `a.length - 1`.

```
        process(a, sum, row++, column);   // increment #1
        process(a, sum, row++, column--); // increment #2
```

Comment: @fge: Well spotted, thanks! I've updated the answer to include this.

Comment: It's calling with the same argument that will cause the stack overflow. If the problem were the double increment, then there would be an array index exception.

Comment: @TedHopp: It's still a bug and will manifest itself when the other bug is fixed

Comment: Agreed. OP almost certainly wants the equivalent of `row + 1` in both calls to `process` (as well as `column - 1` in the second call). But note that `process` is never called with the second increment value, so `row` can never really exceed `a.length - 1` on any call.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
process(a, sum, row++, column);
process(a, sum, row++, column--);
```

Note that the post-increment and post-decrement operators increment or decrement a variable, and then return the **old value** of the variable. So, in the first of these two lines, you are calling the method `process` with the exact same values as the original call. That will then call the method again with the same values, etc., until the call stack overflows.

Answer (score 0):

This line `process(a, sum, row++, column);` calls `process(a, sum, row, column)` and `then` it increment row!

Same function with same parameters is called again and again therefore it overflow stack.

This should do the trick : `process(a, sum, ++row, column);` It firsts increment it and then pass it as argument. But then your row will be incremented. If you do not want to do it, simply use : `process(a, sum, row + 1, column);`, it call process function with incremented row meanwhile does not change your row in method it is called from.

Comment: Or, perhaps better, simply use `row + 1` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You call:

```
process(a, sum, row++, column);
```

But you use the *postfix* `++` operator; as a result, the `row` value as an argument to this function *will not change on call* --> infinite recursion if `row` is not exactly equal to `a.length - 1`.

Call:

```
process(a, sum, row + 1, column);
```

Also, check that in the following line you actually meant to be calling:

```
process(a, sum, row + 2, column);
```

and not:

```
process(a, sum, row + 2, column - 1);
```

or even:

```
process(a, sum, row + 1, column - 1);
```

Given your confused use of postfix increments/decrement operators, it is hard to tell what you mean to do...

Hint: in order to avoid that kind of errors in the future, make your method parameters, `row` and `column`, `final`; you will not be able to modify them in the method's body...